# how to join these queries

Tags: mysql

I need help in having these two queries put into one query. e.g i want to search the database for journeys that match the radius of $sql and the radius of $sql2 and get the results that match both.

```
$sql = "SELECT adpastrip_id, 
            ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians($lat) ) * cos( radians( lat1 ) ) * cos( radians( long1 ) - radians($lng) ) + sin( radians($lat) ) * sin( radians( lat1 ) ) ) ) AS distance 
        FROM addgoodstrip 
        HAVING distance < 10 
        ORDER BY distance 
        LIMIT 0 , 20";

$sql2 = "SELECT adpastrip_id, 
            ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians($lat2) ) * cos( radians( lat2 ) ) * cos( radians( long2 ) - radians($lng2) ) + sin( radians($lat2) ) * sin( radians( lat2 ) ) ) ) AS distance 
        FROM addgoodstrip 
        HAVING distance < 10 
        ORDER BY distance 
        LIMIT 0 , 20 ";
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont need a JOIN, all you need to do it produce 2 calculations in the same query

```
$sql = "SELECT adpastrip_id, 
        ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians($lat) ) * cos( radians( lat1 ) ) * cos( radians( long1 ) - radians($lng) ) + sin( radians($lat) ) * sin( radians( lat1 ) ) ) ) 
        AS distance1,
        ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians($lat2) ) * cos( radians( lat2 ) ) * cos( radians( long2 ) - radians($lng2) ) + sin( radians($lat2) ) * sin( radians( lat2 ) ) ) ) 
        AS distance2

    FROM addgoodstrip 
    HAVING distance < 10 
    ORDER BY distance1 
    LIMIT 0 , 20";
```

Which will produce a result set like

```
adpastrip_id    distance1    distance2
1               100          120
2               90           88
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT adpastrip_id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians($lat) ) *
cos( radians( lat1 ) ) * cos( radians( long1 ) - radians($lng) ) +
sin( radians($lat) ) * sin( radians( lat1 ) ) ) ) AS distance,
( 3959 * acos( cos( radians($lat2) ) * 
cos( radians( lat2 ) ) * cos( radians( long2 ) - radians($lng2) ) + 
sin( radians($lat2) ) * sin( radians( lat2 ) ) ) ) AS distance2
FROM addgoodstrip HAVING distance < 10 or distance2<10 ORDER BY
distance ASC LIMIT 0 , 20";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT adpastrip_id, 
        ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians($lat) ) * cos( radians( lat1 ) ) * cos( radians( long1 ) - radians($lng) ) + sin( radians($lat) ) * sin( radians( lat1 ) ) ) ) AS distance 
    FROM addgoodstrip 
    HAVING distance < 10 
    ORDER BY distance 
    LIMIT 0 , 20
    union
    SELECT adpastrip_id, 
        ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians($lat2) ) * cos( radians( lat2 ) ) * cos( radians( long2 ) - radians($lng2) ) + sin( radians($lat2) ) * sin( radians( lat2 ) ) ) ) AS distance 
    FROM addgoodstrip 
    HAVING distance < 10 
    ORDER BY distance 
    LIMIT 0 , 20 ";
```

`Union` will not show you the duplicate rows as it is same as we perform union on sets (a collection of very defined distinct objects), if you need duplicates as well use `union all`

Comment: A union query will not return that match both distance criteria, it will return those that match at least the one, but not necessarily the other one.

Comment: @Shadow union will merge the results of the 2 queries. I hope this is what the OP needs

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you need a join either, just include both calculations in a single query and filter in the `where` clause on both of them to get the results that match both criteria, and order by the least of the distances:

```
SELECT adpastrip_id, 
    ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians($lat) ) * cos( radians( lat1 ) ) * cos( radians( long1 ) - radians($lng) ) + sin( radians($lat) ) * sin( radians( lat1 ) ) ) ) 
    AS distance1,
    ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians($lat2) ) * cos( radians( lat2 ) ) * cos( radians( long2 ) - radians($lng2) ) + sin( radians($lat2) ) * sin( radians( lat2 ) ) ) ) 
    AS distance2

FROM addgoodstrip 
WHERE ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians($lat) ) * cos( radians( lat1 ) ) * cos( radians( long1 ) - radians($lng) ) + sin( radians($lat) ) * sin( radians( lat1 ) ) ) )  <10 AND
    ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians($lat2) ) * cos( radians( lat2 ) ) * cos( radians( long2 ) - radians($lng2) ) + sin( radians($lat2) ) * sin( radians( lat2 ) ) ) )  < 10

ORDER BY LEAST(distance1,distance2) 
LIMIT 0 , 20";
```